# How to add custom menu icon in menubar on macOS with electron?

Tags: macos, electron

I want to add custom menu in menu bar in mac with electron (nodejs).
How can this be done in electron?

As an example there is:

[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [Tray API](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/tray)

Comment: looking at:   tray = new Tray('/path/to/my/icon') . what type of file is that?

Comment: typically a `.png` file